# Building year to date aggregations using SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, running-totals

I need some help with building a monthly aggregation using only SQL.

Imagine the following table:

```
TranID  DateCode    Account Value
   1    20140101        1   5
   2    20140106        1   -3
   3    20140207        1   6
   4    20140409        1   3
   5    20140103        2   3
   6    20140215        2   7
   7    20140519        2   6
```

There are two accounts that have transactions on various dates. I would like to write code that gives me this result assuming we are in July:

```
MonthID     Account YTD
20140101        1   2
20140201        1   8
20140301        1   8
20140401        1   11
20140501        1   11
20140601        1   11
20140701        1   11
20140101        2   3
20140201        2   10
20140301        2   10
20140401        2   10
20140501        2   16
20140601        2   16
20140701        2   16
```

I'm thinking I should be able convert the dates to MonthCode using

```
DATEADD(day, -DAY(DateCode) + 1, DateCode) AS MonthCode
```

I'm thinking I should be able to solve this somehow by joining the table to itself but I don't really get the numbers right. Also I need to somehow get the months without transactions in as well..

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated!

Code to generate the mock data:

```
Create table #Tran(
TranID int identity(1,1),
DateCode Date,
AccountCode varchar(50),
Value int
);

insert into #Tran (DateCode, AccountCode, Value)
values ('20140101', '1', 5),
('20140106', '1', -3),
('20140201', '1', 6),
('20140401', '1', 3),
('20140101', '2', 3),
('20140201', '2', 7),
('20140501', '2', 6);
```

Comment: how to calculate YTD?

Comment: What version of SQL Server please?

Comment: I'm using Sql server 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SQL Server 2012, given this sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE #t(TranID INT, DateCode DATE, Account INT, Value INT);
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX x ON #t(Account, DateCode);

INSERT #t VALUES(1,'20140101',1,5 ),(2,'20140106',1,-3),(3,'20140207',1,6 ),
(4,'20140409',1,3 ),(5,'20140103',2,3 ),(6,'20140215',2,7 ),(7,'20140519',2,6 );
```

I would use this query (imagine the first line as stored procedure parameters):

```
DECLARE @year INT = 2014, @cutoff DATE = NULL; -- just state the year

-- and optionally an explicit cutoff date (leave NULL for today)
SET @cutoff = '20140731';

DECLARE @startdate DATE = DATEADD(YEAR, @year-1900, 0);

;WITH accounts(a) AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT Account FROM #t 
    WHERE DateCode >= @startdate
    AND DateCode < DATEADD(YEAR, 1, @startdate)
),
months(m) AS 
(
  SELECT TOP (12) DATEADD(MONTH, ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
      (ORDER BY s.[object_id])-1, @startdate)
    FROM sys.all_objects AS s
),
s AS
(
  SELECT a.a, m.m, v = COALESCE(SUM(t.Value),0)
  FROM accounts AS a 
  CROSS APPLY months AS m
  LEFT OUTER JOIN #t AS t
    ON t.DateCode >= m.m
    AND t.DateCode < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, m.m)
    AND t.Account = a.a
  WHERE m.m < COALESCE(@cutoff, SYSDATETIME())
  GROUP BY a.a, m.m
)
SELECT 
  MonthID = m, 
  Account = a, 
  YTD = SUM(v) OVER(PARTITION BY a ORDER BY m ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) 
FROM s
ORDER BY a,m;
```

If you are using a version older than SQL Server 2012, then you may want to try some of the alternative approaches here:

- [Best approaches for grouped running totals](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/01/t-sql-queries/grouped-running-totals)

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to write such an answer! I'll try the code out as soon as I am in the office again.

Answer (score 0):

First you will need a table that has all of the months you may need in it which I'll call MonthValue (20140101, 20140201, etc..)

Your query will look like this:

```
SELECT MonthValue.DateCode, #Tran.AccountID,
  (SELECT Sum(Value) FROM #Tran as sub
   WHERE sub.AccountID = #Tran.AccountID 
    AND sub.DateCode BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -DAY(MonthValue.DateCode) + 1, DateCode) AND MonthValue.DateCode) AS YTD
FROM MonthValue LEFT OUTER Join #Tran ON MonthValue.DateCode = #Tran.DateCode
GROUP BY MonthValue.DateCode, #Tran.AccountID
```

I didn't test it, but it should at least get you close to what you need.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try the code when I am in the office again.

Answer (score -2):

```
WITH TestData AS (
SELECT 
    DATEADD(DAY,(-1*DATEPART(DAY,CONVERT(DATETIME,DateCode)))+1,CONVERT(DATETIME,DateCode)) DateCode,
    AccountCode,
    Value
FROM (
    VALUES ('20140101', '1', 5),
    ('20140106', '1', -3),
    ('20140201', '1', 6),
    ('20140401', '1', 3),
    ('20140101', '2', 3),
    ('20140201', '2', 7),
    ('20140501', '2', 6)
) AS T (DateCode, AccountCode, Value)
)
SELECT DISTINCT 
    TD1.DateCode, TD1.AccountCode,
    (SELECT SUM(TD2.Value) Total
     FROM TestData TD2
     WHERE TD2.AccountCode = TD1.AccountCode AND TD2.DateCode <= TD1.DateCode) Total
FROM TestData TD1
ORDER BY TD1.AccountCode, TD1.DateCode;
```

You have to find a way to group the dates into the month of the year, and then perform the calculation such as the above query.

Comment: This doesn't match the OP's desired result, for example it's missing the row `20140301  1  8`. It will also include data from prior years, where the OP just wants current YTD.